# Space in name db sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, console

I have a problem trying to connect to a database with a .db extension.

The problem is that the .db file has spaces in the name and it is something that I can not change, a file without spaces in the name works correctly.

Is there any way to connect?

The name of the file is File Access Monitor.DB

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gY15v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to put the full name of the file in spaces:

```
> sqlite3
sqlite> .open "File Access Monitor.DB"
```

Or if you're starting directly from the command line:

```
sqlite3 "File Access Monitor.DB"
```